# DB2 - Query to update 10000 rows at time

Tags: sql, db2

I have a large DB2 table containing around 6 million rows which I need to update. Can someone please suggest a way to make this update for 10000 rows and then pick up the next 10000 and so on.

One of the ways suggested in some portals is to put a where condition on one of the fields within the table. However there's no field in the table which I can use to do this.

Comment: Is there a way to see which you already updated?

Comment: A session table containing the primary-key's of rows to be updated, and a status-column indicating which rows have been updated - can be a convenient pattern, and allow restarts from point of failure etc.

Comment: Do you mean that the table has no PK ??? 8-(

Comment: @juergend, no, the update query is to mask personal information in the table (For Ex: NAME field - John is updated to Zxcv). So after updating 10000 rows, I cannot differentiate whats already updated.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez - The table has primary key but how can I use the Primary key to divide the table into chunks of 10000 rows in an automatic way?

Comment: @mao, I do not have access to create any new tables within the database.

Comment: If you use  TOP 10000 wher PK > lastPK  and save the MAX of your PK to last PK, you get chunks....

Comment: Declare Global Temporary does not require createtab privileges, it only needs a minimum of USE rights on a user-temporary-tablespace (which must pre-exist). The session-table disappears automatically when your session-closes.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHonorez,  could you please provide the SQL to do what you have suggested?

Comment: Thanks @mao, could you please provide the SQL to do what you have suggested ?